# How can I reseed a table for Merge replication when it has reach its max identity value. Software is hard coded as int so cannot change datatype?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, replication

I have a client using SQL 2008R2 and they have Merge replication in place. They have hit the max range on a few of their tables because the subscriptions were being removed and readded multiple times. The table on the publisher only contains 175000 row and is replicating to 7 other sites so they should be no where close to hitting the max.

How can I reseed the table and keep all the data intact? I tried copying the table and then dropping the table and renaming it but the identity ranges values stay the same. I cannot change the data type because the uses of Int as a datatype is hard coded into our software.

Any help would be appreciated.

Table looks like this and the rownum is the id column.

```
        rowguid, uniqueidentifier,
       ,contactid, float,
       ,RowNum, int,
       ,type, int,
       ,createdby, varchar(30),
       ,assignedto, varchar(30),
       ,createddate, int,
       ,modifieddate, int,
       ,startdate, int,
       ,duedate, int,
       ,completedate, int,
       ,duration, int,
       ,tickler, int,
       ,priority, smallint,
       ,therule, int,
       ,status, int,
       ,private, tinyint,
       ,flags, int,
       ,subject, int,
       ,notes, text
```

Comment: You want to reseed your table so new entries start from the seed value?  Your question is not clear.  There is no `rownum` column in your table.

Comment: The rownumber has reached its max value 2.1 billion. I want to take the current data and reseed the rownum values so that they start over so instead of having row nums in order like this 1,2,3,4,522,6005,100005666 they are reorder into 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Your question is very clear.  I have run into this problem many times.  During a maintenance window, you need to drop the article from the publication, resequence the Identities, and the add the article back into the publication.  The hard part will be writing the script to resequence the Identities.  We do this using a cursor with a counter to fill in the gaps.

Comment: I see you live in Post Falls.  Nice area.

Comment: I have some sample scripts that I am not comfortable posting here due to their proprietary nature.  However, I can send you a sample script offline.  I'll see if I can find you on LinkedIn.